# Where is the mistake in computation of $\int\!\frac{\mathrm dx}{10x-3}\;?$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{10x-3}=$ ?

Obviously, if we say $\,u=10x-3\,,\,$ then integration becomes

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\int\frac{\mathrm du}{u}=\frac {1}{10}\ln(10x-3)+c$

However, I approach this question like

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{10}\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x-\frac{3}{10}}\;,\;\;$ then $\;\;\dfrac{1}{10}\ln\left(x-\dfrac{3}{10}\right)+C.$

What am I missing ?

Comment: It is the same up to an additive constant $\frac{\ln 10}{10}.$

Comment: I am sorry but how can you see the difference between them is $\ln10 /10$

Comment: $\ln(10A)=\ln(10)+\ln(A).$

Comment: It would be silly question but still I cant see

Comment: The two results are equal, in fact $\,C=c+\frac1{10}\ln10\,.\;$

Comment: $$\frac {1}{10}\ln(10x-3)+c=\frac {1}{10}\ln(10(x-3/10))+c=\frac {1}{10}(\ln(10)+\ln (x-3/10))+c.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification. Now I fully understand

Comment: Btw, beware that an antiderivative of $\frac1u$ is not $\ln u$ but $\ln|u|.$

Comment: Also don't forget that the standard antiderivative of 1/x is ln|x| + C (not ln(x) + C).

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln(\frac{a}{b})=\ln(a)-\ln(b)$$
so $\frac{1}{10}\ln(x-\frac{3}{10})+C=\frac{1}{10}\ln(\frac{10x-3}{10})+C=\frac{1}{10}\ln(10x-3)-\frac{1}{10}\ln(10)+C$
but $-\frac{1}{10}\ln(10)+C$ is constant so let it equal $K$
then $$\frac{1}{10}\ln(10x-3)-\frac{1}{10}\ln(10)+C=\frac{1}{10}\ln(10x-3)+K$$